# Отображение и скрытие элементов

Tags: jquery

У меня есть такая табличка. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы по клику на элемент с классом `table__row_active` открывались все элементы с классом `table__row_noactive` до следующего класса `table__row_active`

```
<table>
  <tr class="table__row table__row_active">
    <td class="table__content">
        <strong class="table__content--bold">Заголовок</strong> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="table__row table__row_noactive">
    <td class="table__content">
        Текст 1
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="table__row table__row_noactive">
    <td class="table__content">
        Текст 5
    </td>
</tr>


<tr class="table__row table__row_active">
    <td class="table__content">
        <strong class="table__content--bold">Заголовок</strong> 
    </td>
    <td class="table__content"></td>
    <td class="table__content"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table__row table__row_noactive">
    <td class="table__content">
        7777
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="table__row table__row_noactive">
    <td class="table__content">
        88
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
.table__row_noactive {
  display: none;
}
$(document).on("click", ".table__row_noactive", function(){
    $(this).find(".table__row_noactive").toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
$('.table__row_active').on('click', function(){
   var $_this = $(this);
   var thisIndex = $_this.index();
   var $table = $_this.closest('table');
   $table.find('.table__row').each(function(){
      if ($(this).index() <= thisIndex) {
         return;
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('table__row_active')) {
         return false;
      }
      $(this).show(); // or $(this).addClass('show');
   });
});
```

Comment: данный вариант не подходит, потому что в таблице может быть несколько тр и привязываться только к первому совсем не вариант

Comment: используйте ID элемента по которому нажали и начинайте от него по индексу проверку по этому же принципу.

Comment: спасибо выручили!

Comment: обращайтесь )))))